# Добавление элемента в конец списка

Tags: c++

Создал список из 5 элементов. Нужно добавлять элементы в конец списка. 
Хочу добиться того, чтобы:
1) Он просил ввести мне элемент (только один) и чтобы он записался в конец
2) При этом все позиции кроме последнего выводятся как:
1.---
2.---
3.---
4.---
5.Введенный мной элемент

Потом просит меня ввести еще, при этом он добавляет его уже в 4 позицию, т.к 5 уже занят. Получается:
1.---
2.---
3.---
4.Мой элемент
5.Мой элемент

Вот кусок кода, при необходимости могу и добавить весь:

```
 if (v == 'n')
 {
  start:
    cout << " List is Empty! Please Enter Elements for the List:n";

    string x, y, z, a, b;          // элементы списка

    string array[] = { x, y, z, a, b };
    for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
    {

        getline(cin, x);
        cout << endl;
        getline(cin, y);
        cout << endl;
        getline(cin, z);
        cout << endl;
        getline(cin, a);
        cout << endl;
        getline(cin, b);
        cout << endl;

        cout << "---------------";
        cout << endl;

        List L;                    // Сам список L

        L.ElAdd(x);                // Добавление элементов в список
        L.ElAdd(y);
        L.ElAdd(z);
        L.ElAdd(a);
        L.ElAdd(b);

        cout << endl;

        L.print();                 // Вывод элементов списка L
    }
```

Comment: Где закрывающая скобка в цикле for?

Comment: я кусок отправил, поэтому скобка исчезла, она была внизу (т.к после этого еще 1 такой цикл был, для удаления элементов). Добавил.

Comment: Какую задачу вы хотите решить таким странным способом?

Comment: 1) Все это что-то непонятное вокруг какого-то списка (наверное, односвязного). Какую задачу Вы пытаетесь решить? 2) Пунктуация в вопросе запутывает читающего.

Comment: @navi1893 лучше отредактируйте вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, что у Вас не получается

Comment: надеюсь щас более понятен вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Вместо c-массива строк лучше воспользоваться `vector<string>`, а добавление с конца можно сделать примерно так:

```
vector<string> array(5, "--"); //Массив из 5 строк вида "--"
for( vector<string>::reverse_iterator iter = array.rbegin();
     iter != array.rend(); ++iter)
{
  string element;
  // чтение строки из консоли ввода
  array.insert(iter, element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем Вам список, если у Вас есть замечательный массив `array`?

Comment: Он изучает списки, это **не** практическая задача.

Comment: @avp странная задача на списки

Comment: @Андрей @app нет, это список, просто я элементы записал в виде массива, т.к в будущем мне понадобится добавлять элементы в определенную позицию.